# Handling errors

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I am trying to perform some operations over some data, but they are not working and I need to find a way to ignore those cells which don´t meet all the requirements.

Basically, I have a column where some cells have text + numbers in their content and other have only text. I search inside all of them and split TEXT in one column and NUMBER in another one. Then, I run a macro to find the matching text to each one in other column.

But when I try to split TEXT from NUMBERS, I search for the first "(", cause my number format is (10.10.10), but if it is not found, the cell value appears: #VALUE!  (ok, it is expected cause the character was not found). Here is the problem: if I run my macro over "#VALUE! it crashs and don´t finish its execution.

I have tried to use

> On Error GoTo

in my macro code, but for some reason it doesn´t not handle the "Run time error: Type Mismatch".

```
For contadorOr = 2 To colO
  For contadorDes = 2 To colA
        On Error GoTo cont
        If InStr(1, Cells(contadorDes, colunaDestino).Value, Cells(contadorOr, colunaOrigem).Value) Then
            If InStr(1, Cells(contadorOr, colunaOrigem + 4).Value, Cells(contadorDes, colunaDestino + 1).Value) Then
                Cells(contadorOr, colunaOrigem + 5).Value = "Mesma versão"
            End If

            Exit For
        End If
    Next contadorDes
cont: Next contadorOr
```

Any suggestions? I can think of ignoring this error (when it´s happen, my variable contadorOr is incremented and go to no next value) or any way to avoid #VALUE! returned by my functions, but haven´t had success doing that.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: On what line does this error occur?

Comment: Excel 2010. This error occur here: If InStr(1, Cells(contadorDes, colunaDestino).Value, Cells(contadorOr, colunaOrigem).Value) Then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using error handling options you could check if cell which you are going to check/process doesn't return error. This is quite simple as presented below:

```
If IsError(Cells(contadorDes, colunaDestino).Value) Then
      'to do anything if there is error
      'usually...do nothing
Else
      'do what you want if there is no error
End if
```